# assign different value to python object

Tags: python

I want to make a python class named "Foo" that has an attribute called "x" which is an int with a default value of 0.
If I assign a posetive value to x it would automatically change to 10 and if I assign a negative value it  would change it to -10. for example:

```
>>p = Foo()
>>print(p.x)
0
>>p.x = -45
>>print(p.x)
-10
>>p.x = 85
>>print(p.x)
10
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Make it a property, so you can define a method to update the value.

Comment: Sounds like you want a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize the `property` decorator:

You first define `_x` as a class member in the constructor:

```
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 0
```

and initialize it with `0`.

Then you define `x` as property:

```
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x
```

This means that we can get the values of `_x` through the name `x`.

Then you define setter for `x` with `@x.setter`:

```
    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = 10 if value > 0 else (-10 if value < 0 else 0)
```

This overrides the original logics for setting value to `x`, with the one that you defined.

ATTENTION: `_x` is still accessible, and if you change it the magic defined above won't hold (there is no `private` class members such as in other languages like C, C++, C#, Java, etc...). Things that start with `_` conventionally means that they are of internal use.

Code:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 0

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = 10 if value > 0 else (-10 if value < 0 else 0)

p = Foo()
# 0
print(p.x)

p.x = -45
# -10
print(p.x)

p.x = 85
# 10
print(p.x)
```